# Predictions based on constrained ordination

Tags: multivariate-analysis, prediction, ecology

This question is aimed at the use of CCA (or similar) in ecology.

What we know for constrained ordination: axes summarizing compositional variation are constrained to be weighted combinations of the predictors.

An easy example:

```
library(vegan)
data(varespec)
data(varechem)
vare.cca <- cca(varespec ~ Al + P + K, varechem)
summary(vare.cca)
```

My question for this example would be: If I have new values for Al, P and K, without Species information, can I obtain predicted values for the ordination axes?

Comment: Not sure what you mean here. Could you please provide a more detailed description of your problem, with a data example?

Comment: I might not be the best with multivariate ordinations but have you tried running environmental data with extra observations with your species x site matrix? I'm assuming it won't run and will give you an error message that should tell you why.